# prevent "abort" in windows batch for npm install

Tags: batch-file, npm

I am writing a bat file to auto install npm packages and install compass. The bat is simple as below:

```
npm install -g bower
npm install -g grunt-cli
npm install
gem update --system --verbose
gem install compass --verbose
pause
```

I find that after each command, the bat file auto aborts and won't run next command. How can I make this simple script run continuously and able to re-run many times?

Comment: Known issue https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/2938

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Possibly the npm program is a batch file itself.
Then you need to use `call`, as only then the program control returns to the caller.

```
call npm install -g bower
call npm install -g grunt-cli
call npm install
call gem update --system --verbose
call gem install compass --verbose
pause
```

Comment: @ChrisLi : It is a batch file - if you're on Windows x64, the location is at: `C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm.cmd`
@jeb: Thanks, your suggestion works perfectly