# Batch file exits after node modules list is returned

Tags: batch-file

I have a very simple batch file that is suppose to query for a list of installed node modules.

However my batch file will automatically closed upon getting the return of the list.

```
@echo off
npm list -g --depth=0
pause
```

Why is this happening as I already have the 'pause' syntax at the end of my script

Comment: Possible duplicate of [prevent "abort" in windows batch for npm install](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19264972/prevent-abort-in-windows-batch-for-npm-install)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably because `npm` is a batch script. Executing one batch script from another will transfer execution. If you want to return when the second script finishes, you need to `call` the second script

```
call npm list -g --depth=0
```

should act as you expect.

No guarantees though, since you don't reveal the precise nature of `npm`.